# Build Failure while while building the Apache Zeppelin

Tags: node.js, maven, npm, apache-zeppelin, yarnpkg

I was installing Apache Zeppelin with Spark and while running the maven install command I get following error for `Zeppelin: web Application`

```
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Zeppelin ........................................... SUCCESS [ 50.394 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Interpreter .............................. SUCCESS [ 31.632 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Zengine .................................. SUCCESS [ 24.134 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Display system apis ...................... SUCCESS [ 19.607 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Spark dependencies ....................... SUCCESS [01:33 min]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Spark .................................... SUCCESS [ 29.058 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Markdown interpreter ..................... SUCCESS [  5.796 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Angular interpreter ...................... SUCCESS [  4.361 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Shell interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [  4.827 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Livy interpreter ......................... SUCCESS [ 50.227 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: HBase interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [ 11.682 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Pig Interpreter ................... SUCCESS [ 10.991 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: PostgreSQL interpreter ................... SUCCESS [  5.541 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: JDBC interpreter ......................... SUCCESS [  6.663 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: File System Interpreters ................. SUCCESS [  6.304 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Flink .................................... SUCCESS [ 13.449 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Ignite interpreter ................ SUCCESS [  5.955 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Kylin interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [  4.915 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Python interpreter ....................... SUCCESS [  6.109 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Lens interpreter ......................... SUCCESS [ 11.360 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Cassandra interpreter ............. SUCCESS [ 58.287 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Elasticsearch interpreter ................ SUCCESS [  9.617 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: BigQuery interpreter ..................... SUCCESS [  5.584 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Alluxio interpreter ...................... SUCCESS [  9.001 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Scio ..................................... SUCCESS [ 48.425 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: web Application .......................... FAILURE [28:26 min]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Server ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Packaging distribution ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 37:14 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-01T16:21:39+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 224M/1792M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:yar
n (yarn install) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'yarn install --no
-lockfile --https-proxy=http://sg0227823:***@tulsa-proxy.sabre.com:80 --proxy=ht
tp://sg0227823:***@tulsa-proxy.sabre.com:80' failed. (error code 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :zeppelin-web
```

Comment: It seems like maven-frontend-plugin failed to execute npm scripts cause the plugin is trying to use local nodejs instead of just installed one. 

Could you install nodejs 6.9.1+ using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and try again?

Comment: If you want to more detailed log, you can add `-X` option to your maven command like `mvn -X ...`

Comment: FYI - https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/2016

Answer (score 1):

As @lambda has mentioned in comments, it was fixed by his PR-2016  github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/2016  but it seems the issue is back in the latest version of Zeppelin.

I resolved this by installing system-wide npm and nodejs:

```
$ sudo yum install nodejs npm
```

(notice if you're using RHEL, both packages are available only through non-default EPEL yum repository https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

but then I was getting 
"Node version 0.10.48 is not supported, please use Node.js 4.0 or higher." when manually ran 'yarn install --no-lockfile' (don't confuse Hadoop's `yarn` command with this `yarn` command - https://yarnpkg.com/en/ which is used by nodejs). This in its turn got resolved by installing latest stable node.js

```
$ sudo npm install n -g
$ sudo n stable
```

ps. It was hard to diagnose what exactly was wrong with yarn command at first as maven just spits 'error code 1', but you can debug by running that same command manually, for example, `./zeppelin-web/node/yarn/dist/bin/yarn install --no-lock` (assuming you're in the root of zeppelin codebase). So you get output of exact problem.